# Get last record of each ID

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I have this query :

```
SELECT  Truck.Name AS name,
        timestamp,
        oil,
        diesel,
        cargo,
        Truck.notes AS Remarks

        FROM trip
        INNER JOIN Truck USING (idTruck)
        WHERE idTruck IN('2','4','5','6','7','8','9','11','12','13','14','15','16')
        ORDER BY name, timestamp DESC
```

which returns ALL records from the ID's 
I was thinking of using CURDATE as

```
AND DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE()
```

in order to get last records but when a record is not modified a day (they usually do but
sometimes this is not the case) I'm loosing the records . How would I modify the query to get the last entry of each idTruck regardless of the timestamp in a single query ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Here's a working  sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/820325/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the MAX function of sql to get the last record (**MAX(Truck.Name)**):

```
SELECT  MAX(Truck.Name) AS name,
        timestamp,
        oil,
        diesel,
        cargo,
        Truck.notes AS Remarks

FROM trip
INNER JOIN Truck USING (idTruck)
WHERE idTruck IN('2','4','5','6','7','8','9','11','12','13','14','15','16')
ORDER BY name, timestamp DESC
```

**To get the last record of each ID :**

```
SELECT  MAX(Truck.Name) AS name,
        timestamp,
        oil,
        diesel,
        cargo,
        Truck.notes AS Remarks

FROM trip
INNER JOIN Truck USING (idTruck)
WHERE idTruck IN('2','4','5','6','7','8','9','11','12','13','14','15','16')
GROUP BY idTruck 
ORDER BY name, timestamp DESC
```

because according to sql.sh(https://sql.sh/fonctions/agregation/max):

> the aggregation function MAX() allows to return the maximum value of a
>   column in a record set. The function can be applied to numeric or
>   alphanumeric data. For example, it is possible to search for the most
>   expensive product in a table in an online shop.

Comment: This brings back only one idTruck  and not the last of each idTruck in the table. I want to get the last entry of all the id's in my where  clause in a single query if possible.

Comment: then you only have to add a **GROUP BY idTruck** like this :  `SELECT  idTruck, MAX(Truck.Name) AS name,timestamp, oil, diesel, cargo, Truck.notes AS Remarks FROM trip INNER JOIN Truck USING (idTruck) WHERE idTruck IN('2','4','5','6','7','8','9','11','12','13','14','15','16') GROUP BY idTruck  ORDER BY name, timestamp DESC ` . Wait. I'll change my answer if that's okay.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer with a little   change of mine : I put MAX(timestamp) and voila :

Comment: Downvoting because it **DOES NOT WORK**.  `GROUP BY` plus `MAX` will correctly get the 'last' value for each group, but it _does not_ get the rest of the columns that correspond to that max.  You must then `JOIN` back to the table to get the other columns that correspond to the max.  See the `[groupwise-maximum]` tag that I added.

Comment: @Dadinaks - Sorry to be harsh on a Newbie.  Your comments about `MAX()` are good.  But the overall answer is a common mistake; I could not let it stand as the accepted and upvoted answer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean doesn't work , It worked perfect for what I wanted with the change I made (replaced MAX(Truck.Name with MAX(timestamp) , as I described in the comment. But who knows, perhaps you now better.

Comment: As much as it hurts you're right . When adding more records it doesn't work as expected, it returns wrong data. Back to start....

Comment: ah okay, no problem.
I actually read an article on [groupwise-maximum] at this link:
[Groupwise Max in MySQL](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)
and I'm gonna try it first because it's new to me.
I'll change my answer if I find a new request.
I'm sorry for the mistakes I've made.
Thanks for the remark @Rick James.